# w3css - Hoverable Dropdown within dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, cascadingdropdown

Using w3.css functionalities, I am trying to write an HTML program to create cascaded dropdown menu with the help of [this](http://jsfiddle.net/sonali9696/ndpatnvt) tutorial.

**My code** is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
    <title>Query Control Panel</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="w3-bar w3-black">
    <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">abc</a>
    <div class="w3-dropdown-hover">
        <button class="w3-button">dropdown-1</button>
        <div class="w3-dropdown-content w3-card-4">
            <div class="w3-bar w3-light-gray">
                <div class="w3-dropdown-click">
                    <button class="w3-button">dropdown-2</button>
                    <div class="w3-dropdown-content w3-bar-block w3-card-4 w3-right">
                        <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">link-1</a>
                        <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">link-2</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="w3-dropdown-click">
                <button class="w3-button">dropdown-3</button>
                <div class="w3-dropdown-content w3-bar-block w3-card-4 w3-left">
                    <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">link-3</a>
                    <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">link-4</a>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

**Output**:
  When I hover over dropdown-1, the elements that should come under dropdown-2 and under dropdown-3 respectively, appear without hovering or clicking.

The following image illustrates the output I am getting when my mouse is over dropdown-1:
   [image]

**Desired Output**:
  When I hover my mouse over dropdown-1, dropdown-2 and dropdown-3 should appear. When I click dropdown-2, only then Link-1 and Link-2 should appear. Similarly, for dropdown-3.

**Fiddle**

Kindly find the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sonali9696/ndpatnvt) here

The external resources used in the fiddle are:
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js
and
https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css

Comment: Can you please make a working fiddle or snippet.

Comment: Well that is likely due to your HTML structure. If you wanted all buttons to be items on the same “level”, then your structure should probably reflect that - by having three independent elements on the same level, whereas you nested 2 & 3 into the dropdown for 1.

Comment: @CBroe I don't want dropdown-1,2,3 on the same level. I want 2 and 3 under 1 just like in the UI. However, I don't want Link-1 and Link-2 to appear only on clicking dropdown-2 or on clicking dropdown-3. It shouldn't appear by just hovering over dropdown-1

Comment: That "tutorial" you are working on uses hover only, it doesn’t work on click. If you want something that only works when clicked, you need to find a different tutorial that explains how that can be achieved using CSS, or you need to use JavaScript to register a click handler on the elements, and in that change their styling accordingly.

Comment: You are required to post a minimal example of the markup that shows the problem here. You aren't showing any CSS: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @BlackPanther Kindly find the fiddle here : 
jsfiddle.net/sonali9696/ndpatnvt

Comment: @CBroe I have updated the link to the more general tutorial from which I had posted the specific example. To include click, there is a minor change required by replacing "hover" by "click"

Comment: @Rob I have included the fiddle in the question. I hope that helps

Comment: No. You are required to post it here, not a third party site that can change or disappear tomorrow helping no one in the future.

Comment: I am sorry, I am unable to understand the issue. The code in the fiddle is the exact same as the code I have posted in the question. My program doesn't involve a separate css code. It is a HTML program which uses w3.css functionalities

Comment: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js
https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css

These are the external resources added in fiddle.
I will mention them in the question as well

Comment: Did you read the link I gave you?

Comment: @Rob yes I did, this time instead of the fiddle code which adds external resources separately. I have provided the code that can run in any editor which can create a .html file.

Comment: @SonaliAgrawal StackOverflow is not meant to JUST answer your quesiton. The goal is for other people to use your question to answer their own. If JSFiddle deletes your css then future readers wont be able to recreate your code to determine if they have the same issue. You should post your CSS here, too.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to build multi-level menu, I've created a fiddle take a look at [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Manoj1991/Zj4eb/820/)

```
<ul class="nav site-nav">
    <li>
        <a href=#>Lorem</a>
    </li>
    <!--
 -->
    <li>
        <a href=#>Ipsum</a>
    </li>
    <!--
 -->
    <li class=flyout>
        <a href=#>Dolor</a>
        <!-- Flyout -->
        <ul class="flyout-content nav stacked">
            <li>
                <a href=#>Foo Bar</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href=#>Bar Baz</a>
            </li>
            <li class="flyout-alt">
                <a href=#>Baz Foo</a>
                <!-- Flyout -->
                <ul class="flyout-content nav stacked">
                    <li>
                        <a href=#>Foo Bar</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href=#>Bar Baz</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="flyout-alt">
                        <a href=#>Baz Foo</a>
                        <!-- Flyout -->
                        <ul class="flyout-content nav stacked">
                            <li class="flyout-alt">
                                <a href=#>Foo Bar</a>
                                <!-- Flyout -->
                                <ul class="flyout-content nav stacked">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href=#>Bar Baz</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="flyout-alt">
                                        <a href=#>Baz Foo</a>
                                        <!-- Flyout -->
                                        <ul class="flyout-content nav stacked">
                                            <li>
                                                <a href=#>Bar Baz</a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href=#>Baz Foo</a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href=#>Foo Bar</a>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href=#>Foo Bar</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href=#>Foo Bar</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href=#>Bar Baz</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="flyout-alt">
                                <a href=#>Baz Foo</a>
                                <!-- Flyout -->
                                <ul class="flyout-content nav stacked">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href=#>Bar Baz</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href=#>Baz Foo</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much what I want! The only difference is that both "Bar Baz" and "Baz Foo" should have drop down.
Could you please help me achieve this by finding out the issue in my code? I don't want to change the look and feel of w3.css

Comment: Could you please create a fiddle for me?

Comment: I couldn't change the above fiddle, but I've made similar navbar please have a look at it  https://codepen.io/manoj1991/pen/BZzPWN

Comment: Thank you for the help! Could you please give me an example where there are 2 dropdowns within a single dropdown i.e. eg. make both "Action" and "dropdown"(under Menu-1)dropdown elements.

Comment: @ManojKadolkar You should probably explain how you fixed it or what you did differently. "give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime
"